# How to typeset the quantum chemistry package ORCA correctly?

Tags: fonts, chemistry

This question is targeted to chemists mainly.

I wonder how to typeset the name of the quantum chemistry package ORCA correctly as shown in the picture.

[image]

Comment: Font looks simiar to Avant-Garde (sans-serif)  try:  `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{avant}
\begin{document}
{\sffamily ORCA}
\end{document}`

Comment: @nidhin This looks perfect. If you turn your comment into an answer, I would be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Font looks similar to Avant-Garde (sans-serif).

#### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{avant}
\begin{document}
{\sffamily ORCA}
\end{document}
```

#### Output:

[image]